# MobileFirst Platform Foundation Operations Console Monitoring and Status

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Product version: 8.0.0.00-20160822-2140
OS: Windows 7
Jdk: 1.7

Greetings,

When accessing the console dashboard from my browser: http://my.example:9080/mfpconsole/index.html#/dashboard the Push service is showing as Inactive and under 'Runtime Status' the state is 'Inactive.' Will the Audit Log provide more clarity as to what the problem is?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Probably not. The audit.log file logs actions done in the console. You should provide the log files that are in the logs folder (devkit-folder/mfp-server/usr/servers/mfp/logs).

Comment: Although you did not state if you're using the Mobile Foundation service, or the DevKit...

Comment: Probably push is not configured/installed during the installation. During installation you will have a option to select where to install push or not.

Comment: @Idan Adar, I am using the Mobile Foundation DevKit on my development machine. There are log files for console, messages, messages_16.09.15_20.56.45.0, stop, and topology. Should I only provide the log files for console?

Comment: Provide the folder in its entirety.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the logs sent via email, checking the network for a firewall rule that blocks some requests, or a restart of the machine may fix this issue.

Suggestions:

- Restart the workstation
- Review firewall for blocking rules